# Phantom category with trivial Hochschild cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

An admissible subcategory $C\subset D$ of a triangulated category is called phantom if $K_0(C)=0$. Such categories may be detected by their Hochschild cohomology (but usually have trivial Hochschild homology). Is there an example of phantom category with trivial Hochschild cohomology?

Comment: An admissible subcategory has trivial Hochschild cohomology iff it is trivial: consider the identity map!